# TestFlight is able to know when I read their email. WHAT?

Tags: testflight, virus

I'm using [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/) for my apps.

When I uploaded a new ipa file to testflight, testflight sent me 1 email.

I only read this email by Mail App on my MAC. I didn't open testFlight app on any smartphone.

And the status is "Email Opened" (following pic)
[image]

How can they do that?
Anyone like me :(, they sent virus via email ?????

Comment: is it HTML mail? probably image-url in the mail that uniquely identifies you

Comment: It's a common technique in eDM ; use an scripted image to know you open the email or not.

Comment: Thanks! I think I must view its raw source

Comment: @StigHausberg You should add your comment as an answer, perhaps with an example to improve this interesting question :)

Answer (score 2):

If this is HTML mail they probably have attached an unique identifier to an image that is loaded externally.

If you have a image in your email that is loaded from the resource

> http://someweb.com/image1.jpg

they change the URL in each email to something like

> http://someweb.com/image1.jpg?youruseridintheirsystem (http://someweb.com/image1.jpg?gf145ffgoo)

When that image is loaded they know that you have opened the email because of your unique identification is in the request.

There are many more ways to do this but this is one way.